# Copy specific text from one worksheet to another

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I receive a daily "pipeline" report of transactions that is used to add that days updates on each specific transaction.  A new worksheet is added for each days business.  Some transactions from yesterdays business will not be on todays list and some transactions on todays list were not on yesterdays report.

I'm trying to create a formula to copy the daily update text from yesterdays report to todays report for that specific transaction without having to manually copy and paste each update.

The formula would be similar to

> =IF(COUNTIFS('2.11'!A:A,A2,'2.11'!ET:ET,"1"),"1","")

but instead of looking for a "1", I need it to copy the note text that was typed in.

2.11 is the worksheet name for yesterdays business
Column A includes all the different transaction names
Column ET is the daily updates/notes that are added

Comment: Take a look at `VLOOKUP`, it should be able to give you desired results.